# Releasing object when you get it from another function

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

**For some unavoidable reasons I have to work on a program with Objective-C and manual memory management environment (no ARC)**.

I am filtering an array that I receive from another function like following:

```
- (void) setNodeAndChildrenCompletion: (TreeNode *) node :(bool) isComplete {
    node.isCompleted = isComplete;
    NSMutableArray *childNodes = [self getFlattenedChildren:node];
    for (TreeNode *node in childNodes) {
        node.isCompleted = isComplete;
    }
}
```

Do I need to release or autorelease the childNodes variable when I am done? I feel I don't need to do anything here but I am not sure. Can someone please help me?

The getFlattenedChildren is further defined as following:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getFlattenedChildren:(TreeNode *) node {
    return [self flattenedNodeArray: node.children];
}

- (NSMutableArray *) flattenedNodeArray:(NSMutableArray*) array {
    NSMutableArray *_flatTodoList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (TreeNode *element in array) {
        [_flatTodoList addObject:element];
        
        if ([element children] != nil) {
            NSMutableArray *array1 = [self flattenedNodeArray:[element children]];
            for (TreeNode *element in array1) {
                [_flatTodoList addObject:element];
            }
        }
    }
    return _flatTodoList;
}
```

Following is init and dealloc:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _todoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _flatTodoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

 (void)dealloc {
    [_todoList release];
    [_flatTodoList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: See [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Comment: Looks like the array passed to you is autoreleased: `NSMutableArray *_flatTodoList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];`.

Comment: FYI - there is no unavoidable reason for using MRC. Even in an MRC project, individual files can be converted to ARC. The trivial amount of time doing the conversion far outweighs all of the issues from staying with MRC.

Comment: @HangarRash If it works, don't touch it. You'll never know what kind of retain/release hocus pocus an old app contains. Converting to modern Objective-C and ARC is not trivial.